# Server Port over from Mac OS to Ubuntu does not work (Express + ReactJS)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I have the exact copy and setting ported to Ubuntu and for some reason I get a

'Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONCE' via chrome DevTools.

The express server is running with PM2 and I have mongoDB running as a service. The goal was to have the server run and connect on reboot (for a store POS system).

On my Mac, it runs connect and such forth no problem.

On my Ubuntu box, the React app *does* launch, I just cannot seem to connect to the database. The db setting are the exact same (ports and all) from my mac to ubuntu.

I used MongoDB Compass on the ubuntu system to view the database once the service is started and it *does* connect, and I see all of the migrated data. When I use postman to try to get a response from my server, it just hangs and nothing happens. I'm not even sure how to diagnostic this issue.

Please inform me what information you need and I'll happily forward it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that on my mac, I didn't have a `process.env.MONGOLAB_URI` setup, so it went to the testDB. But, it seems that on my Ubuntu system there is a default process.env that got created or is used.

```
var mongoUri = process.env.MONGOLAB_URI || 'mongodb://localhost/testDB'
mongoose.connect(mongoUri);
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
```

simply change this line to this

```
var mongoUri ='mongodb://localhost/testDB'
```

allowed it to work. Future note on migration if anyone runs into this problem!